# Pasar tablas de MyISAM a InnoDB en MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

Tengo una base de datos que almacena contenido de hace varios años en diversas tablas.

Todas las tablas están actualmente en `MyISAM` y yo quiero pasarlas todas a `InnoDB`.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo sin correr riesgos de pérdida de datos?

No pongo lo que he intentado hasta ahora, porque de hecho no he intentado nada, es un paso delicado y no quiero poner en riesgo los datos.

Aunque `MyISAM` no maneja restricciones, y ahora sí pienso usar restricciones (al migrarlas a `InnoDB`), por esa parte no hay problemas, en el proceso de inserción de datos en la tabla se ha observado que no haya registros huérfanos (aunque pueda haber dos o tres). Lo que quiero decir es que el tema de las restricciones no sería una dificultad mayor.

Gracias por la ayuda.

**P. D.:** Agradecería la respuesta de alguien que tenga experiencia en este tipo de migraciones.

Answer (score 1):

Una vez lo hice y no tuve problemas,creo es más problemático cuando lo haces a la inversa por el tema de las foreign keys, aunque sinceramente no soy experto. Primero que todo haz un backup, por si algo fallará. Solo tiene que utilizar el siguiente comando(aunque es por tabla):

```
ALTER TABLE `tabla` ENGINE=INNODB
```

Te dejo un articulo que pudieras leer (inglés) sobre los posibles problemas: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/converting-tables-from-myisam-to-innodb/.

IMPORTANTE: Siempre haz respaldo de tu información por si llegaras a tener problemas.

Comment: Hacer este tipo de ALTER te bloquea la tabla y si tiene muchos datos puede ser por minutos hasta horas, en ese caso deberías hacer la misma operación pero con esta herramienta de Percona que evita el problema del bloqueo: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html